# What happens to the bar magnet field when it breaks?

Tags: magnetic-fields

References says alignment of a magnetic field of a bar magnet remains same even if we cut it into two or more pieces. According to this cut edges should attract with each other. When I tried it was working in the opposite way. why is it so ?

Comment: I'm highly skeptical of your claim.  For this to happen, the piece with the original "N" pole would have had to flip its polarity (it can't have two "N" poles).   Unless you did something creative like cutting it along the N-S axis :-)

Comment: Got any pictures/video?

Comment: I m also skeptical. When you cut a magnet SN in the middle  you get SN SN in the two pieces and the fragments should attract, as any two magnets with SN orientation. Is it maybe one of those circular magnets for the refrigerator? Then it is like cutting longitudinally, a bar of magnet, and I have not tried it to see what happens. I suppose if there is anisotropy in the cut, it might end up having NN and SS sideways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it seem like a broken magnet's poles flip?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16708/)