# Broken bar magnet repels?

Tags: electromagnetism

**[image: Why a bar magnet broken from between repel on joining again even if the poles are opposite, i.e. North and South.]**

**Why a bar magnet broken from between repel on joining again even if the poles are opposite, i.e. North and South.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it seem like a broken magnet's poles flip?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16708/)

Comment: Odd, I can't find a good answer to this question on this site even though it's such a common one.